# I can not to run html code coverage in phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit

I created class and named it user info and put it in folder `D:\work\GitHub\api\test`.

I request in command line

```
phpunit --coverage-html D:\work\GitHub\api\logs\
```

After running this command system show me information about about commands in phpunit and report wasn't in `D:\work\GitHub\api\logs\`
my xml configuration file wrote like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<phpunit
        bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
        backupGlobals="true"
        backupStaticAttributes="true"
        colors="true"
        convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
        convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
        convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
        stopOnFailure="false"
        verbose="true"
        syntaxCheck="true">

      <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="unit">
            <directory>test/unit/</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="integration">
            <directory>test/integration/</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="functional">
            <directory>test/functional/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">D:/work/GitHub/api/src/</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <logging>
       <log type="coverage-html" target="/logs/report" charset="UTF-8"      lowUpperBound="35"
       highLowerBound="70"/>
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the configuration file.

Try this:

```
phpunit --configuration /full_path_to_xml/phpunit_config.xml
```